# Error in the ViewPager

Tags: android

I use PagerView in my application. But I have mistake. I load image in each pages. On all pages I see my images. but the page that has a position 0 in pagerAdapter is empty always. What I do not correctly?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String TAG = "State";
static ViewPager pager;
static PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
public static MainActivity activity;
static final int PAGE_COUNT = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activity = this;
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    final ArrayList<String> imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    imagePaths.add("http://tlt.ru/uploads/2014/05/94e1e91067997356912d68e0acc36d31_x240.jpg");
    imagePaths.add("http://tlt.ru/uploads/2014/05/d2cb96bd2e26fd19c4ec5a125d8a6ada_x240.jpg");
    imagePaths.add("http://tlt.ru/uploads/2014/05/6bc17baed9ef08a7aa1c68db2dcd650c_x240.jpg");

    pagerAdapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(activity, imagePaths);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);
            //  update();
            FullScreenImageAdapter.startRefresh(imagePaths.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public static void update() {
    // pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    //  refreshView(pager.getCurrentItem());
    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public static class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static  TouchImageView imgDisplay;
    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {



        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container,
                false);

        imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        //          BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //          options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        //          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                Refresh mt = new Refresh();
                try {
                    mt.execute(new URL(_imagePaths.get(position)));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            } 
        }, 300);
        //  imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    public static void startRefresh(final String url) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                Refresh mt = new Refresh();
                try {
                    mt.execute(new URL(url));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            } 
        }, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
```

How I can load image in page[0]?

Answer (score 0):

I thikn the problem is in the getItemPosition, try this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition (Object object){
  int index = _imagePaths.indexOf(object);
  if (index == -1)
    return POSITION_NONE;
  else
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the position, you can find a better solution for pager [here](http://firstcode.info/example-of-viewpager-with-custom-pageradapter/). You need to Modify activity_main.xml to include android.support.v4.view.ViewPager in layout.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidviewpagerapp;

import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ViewPager viewPager;
 MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
  myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
  viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

 }

 private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

  int NumberOfPages = 5;

  int[] res = {
   android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert,
   android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
   android.R.drawable.ic_menu_compass,
   android.R.drawable.ic_menu_directions,
   android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery};
  int[] backgroundcolor = {
   0xFF101010,
   0xFF202020,
   0xFF303030,
   0xFF404040,
   0xFF505050};

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return NumberOfPages;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
   return view == object;
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

      TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
      textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      textView.setTextSize(30);
      textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
      textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));

      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
      imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);
      LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

      LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
      layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolor[position]);
      layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
      layout.addView(textView);
      layout.addView(imageView);

      final int page = position;
      layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
      "Page " + page + " clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }});

      container.addView(layout);
      return layout;
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
   container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
  }

 }

}
```